# Cannot save process ID of a process in a Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm just trying out shell script in Unix. I want to capture the process id of a process running on port number 1337. So I have written the following piece of code:

```
echo -e "Test Starts"
process_id= /bin/ps -fu $USER| grep 1337 | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'
echo $process_id
```

and saved it in a file called `auto.sh`

Now when I run the following command:

`./auto.sh`

I get the output given below:

```
Test Starts
9067
```

The `$process_id` is never echoed. So my guess is, it's not being stored.

I looked into the following, but didn't help

[Link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157133/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-and-invoke-kill-9-on-it-in-the-shell-script)
[Link 2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-save-the-pid-of-a-process-at-the-time-of-process-startup-913576/)

Comment: You need to quote the entire command process_id= '/bin/ps -fu $USER| grep 1337 | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'' or process_id= $(/bin/ps -fu $USER| grep 1337 | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called command substitution: `process_id=$(/bin/ps ...)`.

Comment: @Joao Vitorino: should it be `backticks` instead of `single quotes`?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

1. Backticks `command`
   is the old-style

   `echo` `id -u`
2. `$()` The modern way and more readable

   echo $(id -u)

Both do the same, evaluate what is inside and then return the command result.

When/Why use one o another:

- `` Backticks

  Compatibility with olders shells
- $()

  Hard to distinguish between **`** and **'**  (`'``''`````''`'`)

  Nested command substitution more easy

  echo $(uname && $(echo id -u))

  Linux 15444

\\echo `uname && `echo id -u``

```
 -bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```